# Самый короткий способ записи в файл/чтения из него

Tags: c++

Попался мне такой короткий код, который пытается читать из файла число, и если не может, то пишет туда то, что было в переменной (предполагается, что она проинициализирована):

```
bool     ok = ifstream(filename) >> i;
if (!ok) ok = ofstream(filename) << i;
```

Но правильный ли он? Вопрос вызывает вторая строчка. Если мне память не изменяет, стримы в плюсах буферизированные, и запись в файл произойдет если мы вызовем `close()`, `flush()`, или напишем `<< endl`. Не будет ли такого, что `ok` у нас окажется `true`, но в момент вызова деструктора стрим не сможет записать в файл данные, потому что, например, нет прав на запись в этот файл?

Comment: Если он не смог прочитать число, то в переменной может быть мусор. "*в момент вызова деструктора стрим не сможет записать в файл данные*" - осуществление записи в деструкторе является проблемой

Comment: @VTT, `осуществление записи в деструкторе является проблемой` - почему кстати? Видел полно классов, из разряда бенчмарков где результаты пишутся в файл именно в деструкторе.

Comment: @NewView Потому что делать обработку ошибок в деструкторах крайне затруднительно. Соответственно потенциально неуспешные операции в деструкторе получаются либо фатальными, либо игнорируемыми.

Comment: @VTT, аа, с этой точки зрения, это да, согласен.

Comment: @VTT, если переменная не проинициализирована, там таки будет мусор, предполагается, что она проинициализирована, я поправил это в вопросе. Или там мусор может оказаться прямо после попытки прочитать?

Comment: Если они уже была один раз инициализирована, то неинициализированной она стать в принципе не может. Однако если оператор << реализован некорректно, то после (частично) неудачного чтения объект может казаться в некорректном состоянии и нуждаться в очистке.